# Need Help to Remove this Part ( .php?number= ) from Link

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Need Help to Remove this Part `.php?number=` from Link with `/` using .htaccess

Old link

```
http://travelingasiapacific.com/grameenphone-mobile-phone-number-start-from.php?number=88%2001701000000
```

Needs to look like

```
http://travelingasiapacific.com/grameenphone-mobile-phone-number-start-from/88%2001701000000
```

Comment: well son you might wanna try harder ... http://bit.ly/NVrLlM

Comment: the solution should be very close to the one in your other question, what have you tried till now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved this problem in this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^grameenphone-mobile-phone-number-start-from/(.*)$ grameenphone-mobile-phone-number-start-from.php?number=$1 [L]
```

This code for resizing the link

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

This part for removing .php from link